# Cannot align logo in navbar with buttons

Tags: html, css

I am currently in the process of creating a small website for my university project. I have currently come across a small problem which I cannot seem to fix.

The problem in question is that i have created a navigation bar for my website, and the logo is in the center with buttons equally distributed on each side, the issue I face is that the buttons are not aligning themselves with the logo and it causing the navigation bars height to increase. I have provided an image of the issue along with the HTML and CSS code of the section in question.

This is the HTML for the navbar section.

```
    <nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="forum.html">FORUM</a></li>
        <li><a class="logo" href="index.html"></a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BASKET</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

This is the CSS

```
#navbar {
display: block;
text-align: center;
height: 90px;
margin-bottom: 3%;
background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

#navbar ul { 
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px 0px; 
margin: 0px 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar ul li {
display: inline-block; 
}

#navbar ul li a { 
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 15px; 
width: 95px;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 60px; 
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
}

#navbar .logo {
background: url("../images/logo1.png") 50% 0 no-repeat;
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
padding: 0 0;
margin: 0 0;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Images of the issue : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEz4Q.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:flex` on your nav to fix this

```
#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```